# I literally have no idea how to start the problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that for any real constants a and b, where a > 0,
(n + a)^b = Θ(n)^b

I have never done a problem like this and don't know how to start the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I figured it was discrete mathematics, which is relatable to coding.